# Example from ?aggregate documentation generates error

Tags: r, aggregate

Why is this not working for me:

I pasted in the following example from R help:

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, mean)
```

I am getting following error every time

```
Error in m[[2L]][[2L]] <- parse(text = lhs)[[1L]] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

However the following works:

```
aggregate(len ~ ., data = ToothGrowth, mean)
```

Surprised ...

Edits: session information is provided

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doBy_4.4.0         MASS_7.3-11        snow_0.3-6         lme4_0.999375-39   Matrix_0.999375-46 lattice_0.19-17   
 [7] multcomp_1.2-6     mvtnorm_0.9-96     R2HTML_2.2         survival_2.36-5    reshape_0.8.4      plyr_1.4          
[13] rcom_2.2-3.1       rscproxy_1.3-1     Biostrings_2.18.4  IRanges_1.8.9     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Biobase_2.10.0 grid_2.12.2    nlme_3.1-98    stats4_2.12.2  tools_2.12.2
```

Comment: That example runs fine for me. I recommend you try again, maybe typing it directly (not copy/paste), and if that fails, try adding some info on the version of R you're running and your OS.

Comment: The code from the example works for me.  That leads me to believe you (or a package you loaded) have re-defined something important.  Please add your `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with some of those packages. As Joshua said, try running the aggregate() code in a new session with only the base packages loaded. Also, as a general recommendation, I'd suggest upgrading R to the current version, if you can.

Comment: I tried typing before posting as I did not want to bother anybody..I was using Rstudio, now I pasted in Rgui works for me too ! surprised again...is there any disadvantage of using Rstudio ?? I have not realized before ....

Comment: I doubt the problem was specific to RStudio (although anythings possible, I suppose). More likely it was as Joshua said; you or a package redefined something important.

Comment: How can remove, I mean temporary i.e. detach, all attached packages? Is there any command to do so ?

Comment: running R in `--vanilla` mode can be handy for solving these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

This question is partially solved. I used a fresh R session, pasted code and got what I want. Potentially the package or something I define in the session are causing problem ( I do not know), as suggested here see prov.

Comment: Suggest you close then, it seems irreproducible.